# Keep form's fields after clicking on button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

While attempting to keep my `form`' s fields comprising of:

```
<select ...>
<option></option>
</select>
```

from my `page.aspx`, after clicking on a `submit` `button`:

```
<input type="button" id="btnEn" value="Submit" runat="server" onserverclick="btnCalc_Click" style="margin-left:30px; border-radius:0; width:50px; font-size:14px;background-color:#c1c1c1"/>
```

I have amended the `form`'s `tag` with `onsubmit="return false"`
.

However it looks like `onsubmit="return false"` deactivates `btnEn`, since it does not call anymore `protected void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` held in `page.cs`.

I've tried other solutions involving `UpdatePanel`, which did not yield the expected outcome: call the `btnCalc_Click()` `method` while keeping in the form values displayed in the `textboxes`, selected `dropdown list`, after click.

Thus, any idea (*ideally with a minimum of javascript if the latter represents the panacea to this issue*) would be appreciated as I'd like to keep calling my `bntCalc` (written in C#).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a server control instead of the html  element.

The ASP.Net Webforms DropDownList control renders a select and a set of option tags, and mantains state using ViewState.

For example, this code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

will render as:

```
<select name="ddl" id="ddl">
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

And by default will preserve selected value. In the webform, you can access control value using this.ddl.SelectedValue.

Note: the "return false" in the javascript event handler cancels the event. Is standard html/javascript behaviour.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations. I even applied the logic (while using it adequately) to  ```<asp:Textbox/>```, ```<asp:RadioButton/>``` yielding the expected outcome. However, ```<asp:FileUpload/>``` is still affected by the ```button.click()``` event for a reason that I am still ignoring.

Comment: Hi. The file upload doesn't retain state because of security reasons. It allows the web page to access local resources in user's disk, so it will always start as an empty field. Imagine a page with a hidden (using css) file upload control that upload files as the file with passwords in windows systems, or user configuration files in linux... it will be very risky.

Comment: Very useful knowledge sharing... Thanks, and Best Wishes.